# Mass installation of CentOS 7 (Linux) and configuration

Tags: centos, system-installation

I am planning to install CentOS 7 for 100 servers. I am looking towards automating the procedures and configurations.

I have found several resources online which goes about doing it, but I am not sure which is applicable or more popular for my use case.

It seems that stackiq has the best documentation, but I have to exclude 1 server to be host server to provision the remaining servers.

1. https://www.stackiq.com/downloads/
2. https://cobbler.github.io/
3. https://fai-project.org/
4. https://crowbar.github.io/

Comment: Are these virtual systems? Bare metal? Would a kickstart config and possibly PXE booting suffice instead of using one of those projects?

Comment: These 100 servers are bare metal servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the following is personal opinion garnered from my experience. YMMV.

The only one I have experience with is Cobbler, which I would suggest you avoid. It is not necessarily bad, but the documentation is fundamentally lacking and in various versions/states. I would very much consider Cobbler an alpha or beta release despite any claims otherwise. Many key features, points of information, and details are completely undocumented or documented so poorly as to be meaningless unless you are on the DEV team.

StackIQ looks very promising, and I am looking forward to playing with it myself.

FAI project looks decent, and I like their point about "download a CD image and burn it. Install the first box from the CD, then it becomes the server to network build the rest". That might just be the distinguishing point you need...

Crowbar looks like it is very "DevOps" centric with things like Git integration etc. Might be just the thing, depending on your use case for the systems.

If you have a bit of time to invest in learning, I would recommend setting up a CentOS 7 based PXE-TFTP-syslinux-kickstart server. I don't have a good all-in-one howto handy, but there are multiple guides online that help with the various parts. (I'm at work now, but I may be able to put something together later today.)

Comment: crowbar doesnt seems to have much documentation as well.